# Can I add a conditional in PHP to only display JS on big screens?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, conditional-statements

Basically I am running a JavaScript on one of my pages but I don't want it displayed on mobiles. Is this doable in PHP? I've added an enqueue function in my WordPress child theme as per the below:

```
function load_js_assets() {
if( is_page( 1509 ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-script', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-script2', 'https://unidigital.tech/wp-content/themes/picostrap-child/particles.js?ver=5.6', array('jquery'), false, true);
    
}
```

}

But I haven't managed to succesfully add a condition to only run the JS on big screens. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Are you trying to detect the screen size using only PHP?

Comment: yes, I could just use CSS to not display the JS but it would still run in the background - which I would like to avoid

Comment: Try to use [Mobile Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) to determine the user device

Comment: i dont know too much about wordpress, but maybe you can try detect screen size with javascript first, then load javascript like a example.com/js/xxx.php?screensize=1509

Answer (score 0):

Use the following snippet to enqueue javascript only on non-mobile devices.

```
  

    //Identify is request is coming from a mobile browser.
    function isMobileDevice() { 
        return preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo 
    |fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i" 
    , $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]); 
    } 
    
    function load_js_assets() {
        if( is_page( 1509 ) && !isMobileDevice()) {
            wp_enqueue_script('custom-script', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
            wp_enqueue_script('custom-script2', 'https://unidigital.tech/wp-content/themes/picostrap-child/particles.js?ver=5.6', array('jquery'), false, true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no, you cannot reliably detect the platform with PHP. There are two reasons:

1. PHP runs on the server and has no business on the client-side. There are some hacks using the browser string, however those are platform-dependent and easy to spoof.
2. The line between mobile and not mobile devices is blurry. See answers and comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device)

The best approach is to design your website in such a way that you do not need to make these checks at all.

Answer (score -1):

look at the side of the css are things possible easily

Comment: that wouldn't work as the JS would still run in the background, which I don't want